# How to remove repeat rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to remove repeated records in search result. I have 3 columns (`id`, `worklevel` & `umobile`).

It looks like below:

[image: table]

Red places is repeat but I need just one of them in result.

Comment: You should make the effort to provide sample data and expected results as tabular text and in English. Few people here can read arabic and most want to consume data as tabular text rather than images.

Comment: the arabic fields is same it is not need to know arabic language shapes is same

Comment: What would you expect to see for Column C when the source has a unique value for each row?

Comment: i removed col c in picture since it is users phone numbers

Answer (score 1):

Try using DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: ty guy but it is not work

Comment: Please provide code you tried to run